# How to link my svg images (raphael.js)

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have created an interactive map, using [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com) following [Jonathan Petitcolas tutorial](http://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/07/18/create-clickable-svg-france-regions-map.html).

The only part he skips is how to create links inside the map. I would like to set a target for every part of the map like `href="example.html"`

Although, how can I add `data` to my single paths, that I can target using jQuery? I want to create a mouseover overlay containing information like `north west`, `south`, etc.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/zbr2rshe/2/) – I appreciate every hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `regions` to array of objects, to include `title` and `href` data:

```
regions["yw-arnsberg"] = {href:"www.google.com", title: "mytitle", path: map.path("M 314.3,204.1c2.6-0.9,...")};
```

Inside `for (function (region) {` add code that will deal with the title:

```
region.path.attr({title: region.title});
```

and also add `click` listener that will deal with `href` data:

```
region.path[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    location.href = region.href;         
}, true);
```

**(almost)** working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbr2rshe/4/ JSFiddle does not allow to save any fiddle with `location.href = region.href;` so this fiddle does not contain it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort @Ivan Jovovic. The only part I do not understand is `tooltip: "asdasdasd"`. Am I able to insert any css instead of "asdasdasd" or what values can I use to manipulate the document?

Comment: As for `tooltip: "asdasdasd"` - it has left in Fiddle by mistake. I do not know if you can style `title` tag via `css`.

Comment: Do you know how I am able to target `title: "mytitle"` inside my `regions`? For example insert it as text into a div?